# Set up a Wifi-Direct connection between Android and Raspberry Pi 3 Linux

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, raspbian, p2p, wifi-direct

I want to connect two devices using Wifi-Direct. One is a RaspBerry PI 3 (with Raspbian Jessie), the other is an Android smartphone. Raspberry as server and Android as client.

I decided to use wpa_supplicant in Raspbian and the WifiDirect example app for Android:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html

My wpa_supplicant.conf contains:

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
update_config=1 
device_name=raspberry
device_type=1-0050F204-1
driver_param=use_p2p_group_interface=1
p2p_go_intent=1
p2p_go_ht40=1
```

I am following this steps:

1) In the raspberry pi:

```
sudo wpa_supplicant  -B -iwlan0 -Dnl80211 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
sudo wpa_cli -iwlan0 p2p_group_add
ifconfig p2p-wlan0-0 192.168.1.2
wpa_cli -ip2p-wlan0-0 wps_pbc
```

2) Then in the Android app, I can see the raspberry as a peer but I get a connection failure.
I try with the settings app (*Wifi => Advanced => Wifi Direct*) and I can see the raspberry as a peer too but the diference is that when I try to make the connection, the application request me a PIN code and I am able to make the connection if I introduce the pin returned by p2p_pin any in the raspberry.

Im trying to understand this behavior:

**Why is requesting me a PIN? This is the reason why I am not able to make the connection through the WifiDirect example app? Im missing something here?**

Thank you.

Comment: I am using this page http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/OMAP_Wireless_Connectivity_NLCP_WiFi_Direct_Configuration_Scripts to try to figure out something...Nobody can give me an approach?

Comment: I'm also looking for an answer to this ... maybe you should set the "wifi-direct" tag to improve your chances for an answer ...

Comment: You are right...I will add it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you have:

```
wpa_cli -ip2p-wlan0-0 wps_pbc
```

use:

```
sudo wpa_cli -ip2p-wlan0-0 wps_pin any 12345670
```